# How do you make a UITableView with Sections using NSFetchedResultsController?

Tags: uitableview, core-data, swift5, nsfetchedresultscontroller, sections

So we have to use CoreData and we have to use a UITableView, now I'm asking how does that work with a NSFetchedResultsController? We have something already set up for other basic sectioned views where we dont need a fetchresultscontroller and that was pretty easy, but this seems a little trickier. There is a little support out there for our old pal Objective-C that has been around for years but we are looking for a Swift solution. ***Swift 5*** at the time of this post.

Have already implemented the plain list (which is fairly well documented) and now we just want to add some sections...

Answer (score 0):

So we have a UITableView and a NSFetchedResultsController and we get a nice list of Entities. Now we want to add a few sections into the tableview.
No Problem so we update the sortDescriptors to include a section:

```
     fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = 
          [NSSortDescriptor(key: "sectionLabel", ascending: false),
          NSSortDescriptor(key: "unixTimestamp", ascending: false)]
```

and the entity to include the sectionLabel, this part is a bit more custom depending on what kind of sections you want.

Then we add a few section functions :

```
     func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
          return self.fetchController?.sections?.count ?? 0
     }

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
          guard AllTheThings( fetchController -> sections -> entity -> cell )
          if sections.count > 1 {
            cell.configureCell(value: entity.sectionLabel ?? "myLabel")
            return cell.contentView 
          } else { return UIView() }
     }
     
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 20.0
     }

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
          guard let sections = fetchController?.sections else { return 0 }
          return sections[section].numberOfObjects
    }
```

So things are starting to shape up but theres still some work needed on the `cellForRowAt indexPath` and other standard cell functions. So in order to get an entity for the index to use in those we create a cool function:

```
func returnEntity(indexPath: IndexPath) -> MyEntity? {
        
        guard let sections = fetchController.sections else {
            return nil
        }
        
        guard let objects = sections[indexPath.section].objects else {
            return nil
        }
        
        if objects.isEmpty {
            return nil
        }
        
        guard let entity = objects[indexPath.row] as? MyEntity else {
            return nil
        }
        
        return entity
    }
```

Left the guards in this time ;)

Now all you have to do to get your entity is use `returnEntity(indexPath: indexPath)`